# How can i optimise these loops

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I have the below snippet which takes a long time to run as the data increase.

OrderEntityColection is a List and samplePriceList is a List

OrderEntityColection  = 30k trades
samplePriceList = 1million prices

Takes easily 10-15 minute to finish or more

I have tested this with 1500 orders and 300k prices but it takes around 40-50 seconds as well and as the orders increase so do prices and even takes longer

Can you see how i can improve this. I have alreadyy cut it down to these numbers before in hand from a big set.

MarketId = int
Audit = string

```
foreach (var tradeEntity in OrderEntityColection)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(samplePriceList,new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8}, (price) =>
    {
          if (price.MarketId == tradeEntity.MarketId)
          {
              if (tradeEntity.InstructionPriceAuditId == price.Audit)
              {
                    // OrderExportColection.Enqueue(tradeEntity);
                    count++;
              }
          }

     });
}
```

Comment: If this is EntityFramework (or another ORM) you'll get a huge performance increase by just writing the logic as a simple bit of SQL. Also you'll have a race condition here with a simple `count++` and threaded code.

Comment: Where is this data coming from? This looks like work best done on a database. Joining on a list of a million entries in memory is going to take a while.

Comment: ignore the count++ please as its not required here.

Comment: would tour inner loop comparisons also require that the index of both of your collections be the same? is that expected?

Comment: What state do you need from the loop if you are not using `count`? This is critically important.

Comment: @user1535623 ok, but you've still not told us where this data comes from. This query - with that number of records (and more) done in a database will take milliseconds

Comment: If this is in memory you might want to look at creating a Lookup on `OrderEntityCollection` based on the `MarketId` and `InstructionPriceAudit` so you loop over the collection once to create the lookup and then use it to quickly find the matches to the current `price`.

Comment: I already got the data set from database and the other set from csv files.Have cut it down to that number after scanning million of rows from csv and cutting down orders from database. Now im left to do all the magic in memory

Comment: Can the outer loop also be parallelized?

Comment: @user1535623 You might want to consider loading the csv into the DB.

Comment: Have tried paralleling outer loop as well but didnt help.Sorry im a newbie here so trying to find the best possible optimisation here. I have all my prices in csv (40gb easily)(with 20-30 mill rows). I have extracted 1 million based on prices im interested in and then getting trade details from database (30k trades). Now its a matter of match market id and audit which is common but take alot of time

Comment: Paralellizing this will not help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to do data in memory, ok - you need to be smart about the way you formulate the data up front. First thing is you're getting a list of prices by MarketId - so create that first:

```
var pricesLookupByMarketId = samplePriceList.ToDictionary(
           p => p.MarketId, 
           v => v.ToDictionary(k => k.Market));
```

Now you have a `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,Price>>();` (note ive assumed both MarketId and Audit are ints. If they're not it should still work)

Now your code becomes super simple and a lot faster

```
foreach (var tradeEntity in OrderEntityColection)
{
    if(pricesLookupByMarketId.ContainsKey(tradeEntity.MarketId)
             && pricesLookupByMarketId[tradeEntity.MarketId].ContainsKey(tradeEntity.InstructionPriceAuditId))
    {
          count++;
    }
}
```

Or, if you'er a fan of one long line

```
var count = OrderEntityColection.Count(tradeEntity => pricesLookupByMarketId.ContainsKey(tradeEntity.MarketId)
                 && pricesLookupByMarketId[tradeEntity.MarketId].ContainsKey(tradeEntity.InstructionPriceAuditId))
```

As pointed out in the comments, this can be further optimized to stop repeated reads of the dictionaries - but the exact implementation depends on how you want to use this data in the end.

Comment: to have even better solution, you can use `dict.TryGetValue` to not seek twice across dictionary buckets. Final complexity is `O(N+M)`

Comment: @DmitryPavliv im sure you're right, but do you think that should be done twice (one for the outer lookup and one for the inner)? I cant visualize the change....

Comment: it depends on what OP really wants to do. Taking into account their comment `// OrderExportColection.Enqueue(tradeEntity);` probably it's better to do for both dictionaries

Comment: I think it also could change the foreach with a parallel one. (If the Dictionary is read only it will further optimize the speed by dividing the work )

Comment: @Jamiec, one more correction, looks like you can have multiple prices with same Market / Audit. So dictionary should be `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,List<Price>>>` which can be found by using `groupby`

Comment: I think the inner Dictiory should be `v.ToDictionary(k => k.Audit)`, not `v.ToDictionary(k => k.Market)`

Answer (score 0):

In the parallel loop you have cases, where you skip the processing for certain items. That's quite expensive, as you rely on that check to also happen on a separate thread. I'd just filter out the results first before processing those, as follows:

```
foreach (var tradeEntity in OrderEntityColection)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(samplePriceList.Where(item=>item.MarketId == tradeEntity.MarketId && item.Audit == tradeEntity.InstructionPriceAuditId) ,new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8}, (price) =>
    {
         // Do whatever processing is required here
        Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
    });
}
```

On a side note, seems like you need to replace `count++` with `Interlocked.Increment(ref count)`, to be thread safe.

Comment: this still gives complexity of `O(N*M)`

Comment: Yes. I have optimized it from concurrency perspective, rather than from algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Manage to do this with the help of my friend

```
var samplePriceList = PriceCollection.GroupBy(priceEntity=> priceEntity.MarketId).ToDictionary(g=> g.Key,g=> g.ToList());


        foreach (var tradeEntity in OrderEntityColection)
        {
            var price = samplePriceList[tradeEntity.MarketId].FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.Audit == tradeEntity.Audit);
            if (price != null)
            {
                count+=1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault still enumerates the list for every item, you'd be better with a dictionary solution as with my answer

Comment: @jamiec This syntax doesnt seem to work for me                             
  var pricesLookupByMarketId = samplePriceList.ToDictionary(
           p => p.MarketId, 
           v => v.ToDictionary(k => k.Market));

Comment: define "doesnt work". I had a typo Maybe it was supposed to be `k.Audit` at the end there

Comment: var pricesLookupByMarketId = samplePriceList.ToDictionary(
                p => p.MarketId,
                v => v.ToDictionary(k => k.Market));   It doesnt recognises k.Market. sorry im a newbie so trying to work out the correct syntax here and struggling

Comment: @Jamiec k. does not show any properties on intellisense. do i have to write and overload method in the class for ToDictonary ?

Comment: No its an extension method on `Enumerable<T>` - part of namespace `System.Linq` (add a `using`)